# HttpResponse is returning status code 400, after being set to a custom value

Tags: c#, wcf, httpcontext

I have the following service method which is called on when the following restful url is given `http://xxxxxxxxx/api/checkemail?email={email}` If the length of the email exceeds 254 characters then I want to throw an argument out of range exception, which works okay, and overwrite the http response status code which isnt working.

When i execute the url in fiddler, instead of return the status code 94043 (a random number i wanted to use) it returns 400 bad request. Any ideas why?

```
    public bool CheckIfUserExists(string email)
    {
        if (email.Length > 254)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 94043;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "The email exceeds the maximum character limit";    
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Email", "The email address is greater than 254 characters");
        }
        return CheckIfUserExists(email);
    }
```

Comment: It probably isn't letting you because you shouldn't be inventing your own status codes which aren't part of the Http Spec, and I'm guessing the framework enforces this. Generally, 4xx means some kind of user error, so you should be returning 400 bad request or some other 4xx error code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to use the WebFaultException class. It avoids having to manage the httpresponse object.

```
    public bool CheckIfUserExists(string email)
    {
        if (email.Length > 254)
        {                
            throw new WebFaultException<string>("{EmailTooLong" + ":" + "Error 94043" + "}", System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        return DBUtility.CheckIfUserExists(email);
    }
```